# setTimeout is executing function before time

Tags: settimeout

Hi,

I have this code:

```
setTimeout(OverlayScrollbars(document.getElementById("content"), {}), 14000);
```

but the function is being executed right away rather than waiting 14 seconds before initializing. Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: It's because you are calling the function immediately - you are not passing the function itself to setTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a callback function.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    OverlayScrollbars(document.getElementById("content"), {});
}, 14000);
```

They way you wrote it you were passing the return value of the `OverlayScrollbars` call as the callback function, which is probably not what you intended.